# onActivityResult callback when installing an app from Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-intent, callback, installation, google-play

I guess the short question is: Is it possible to get a working callback with onActivityResult after installing / not installing an app from Google Play Store?

I can send the user to an app (assuming they have Google Play Store and using the package name in the url) with:

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
marketIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
startActivityForResult(marketIntent, 1);
```

I would like to get the result here:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: user accepted the install");
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: user cancelled the install");
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: failed to install");
        }
    }
}
```

I would prefer to use `Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` rather than an `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` for the installation, but information regarding how to use the former is limited. However, `Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` appears to be deprecated from API level 29, so I accept solutions that use `PackageInstaller` too.

By the way, the code I posted is flawed because it always returns `resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED` when returning to the app.

Comment: Few years back, i was also searching the same answer.
I even tried getting the list of all installed app before executing the intent and then compare it with the newer list after one hour. but even that's not good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Possible solution is you have to programatically check with below method for the particular package Name before redirecting user to playstore that whether the app is installed or not.And then in OnActivityResult callback again check it with below method.

```
private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).enabled;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does actually work to include it in the callback, since the requestCode always triggers but the resultCode is wrong. I'll wait a bit to see if other answers are posted before accepting, thank you for understanding.

Comment: you will always get cancelled result, as you pressed back to return on your app regardless of where user redirected. even if the the app don't exist on play store

Comment: @ErlendK.H. Please accept the answer if it has help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer is - **NO, it's not possible**

You cannot get callback if the user you redirected, installed the application

I am not aware of your exact use case here, but if it involve work related to referral then i suggest you to look [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer). Google Play Install Referrer can provide information